# Forward geocoding did not work with CLGeocoder but works as expected on Apple Native Map

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I tried to use the Apple GeoCoderDemo to do the forward geocoding. I tried with "Walmart Michigan", and results returned back are totally different by comparing with apple's native map app on the device.

After searching stackOverflow, I know that CLGeocoder can only do address search instead of address/business name search, which meaning it is looking for street name contains with Walmart in Michigan in my case.

But I am curious to know why the apple's native map can do the work perfect. Does anyone know the secret for that?

Thanks for all helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 6.1, Apple exposed us to [`MKLocalSearch`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKLocalSearch/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012893), which is a true search function, akin to what the Maps app does. For example:

```
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = @"restaurant";
request.region = mapView.region;

MKLocalSearch *localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSMutableArray *annotations = [NSMutableArray array];

    [response.mapItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(MKMapItem *item, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        CustomAnnotation *annotation = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] initWithPlacemark:item.placemark];
        annotation.title = item.name;
        annotation.phone = item.phoneNumber;
        annotation.subtitle = item.placemark.addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
        [annotations addObject:annotation];
    }];

    [self.mapView addAnnotations:annotations];
}];
```

Comment: @ Rob: Worked as a charm. Thanks